# twitter api to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

Love your help here. I just want to grab all tweets from my handle and ump into MySQL db. Even though it prints okay I am not able to store my tweets into MySQL table. I just want to grab all the tweets from one handle and move it to mysql. Code below runs in loop but does not inserts records.

Below is all my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import twitter
import tweepy
import json
import mysql.connector
from dateutil import parser
consumer_key = 'a'
consumer_secret = 'a'
access_token = 'a'
access_token_secret = 'a'

CONSUMER_KEY = 'a'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'a'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'a'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'a'

HOST = "localhost"
USER = "admin"
PASSWD = "admin"
DATABASE = "twittertest"

# Creating the authentication object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
# Setting your access token and secret
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
# Creating the API object while passing in auth information
api = tweepy.API(auth)
# The Twitter user who we want to get tweets from
name = "gsitableau"
# Number of tweets to pull
tweetCount = 2000

# This function takes the 'created_at', 'text', 'screen_name' and 'tweet_id' and stores it
# into a MySQL database
def store_data(created_at, text, screen_name, tweet_id):
    db=mysql.connector.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO twitter (tweet_id, screen_name, created_at, text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (tweet_id, screen_name, created_at, text))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):    
    #This is a class provided by tweepy to access the Twitter Streaming API. 

    def on_connect(self):
        # Called initially to connect to the Streaming API
        print("You are now connected to the streaming API.")

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        # On error - if an error occurs, display the error / status code
        print('An Error has occured: ' + repr(status_code))
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        #This is the meat of the script...it connects to your mongoDB and stores the tweet
        try:
           # Decode the JSON from Twitter
            datajson = json.loads(data)

            #grab the wanted data from the Tweet
            text = datajson['text']
            screen_name = datajson['user']['screen_name']
            tweet_id = datajson['id']
            created_at = parser.parse(datajson['created_at']) 

            #print out a message to the screen that we have collected a tweet
            print("Tweet collected at " + str(created_at))

            #insert the data into the MySQL database
            store_data(created_at, text, screen_name, tweet_id)

        except Exception as e:
           print(e)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
#Set up the listener. The 'wait_on_rate_limit=True' is needed to help with Twitter API rate limiting.
listener = StreamListener(api=tweepy.API(wait_on_rate_limit=True)) 
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=listener)
print("Tracking: " + str(name))
streamer.filter(track=name)
```

Above is all the whole code

Comment: What can't you make work? Where do you call `store_data`, and what happens?

Comment: it succeeds and goes on like a loop saying data collecting in repeat mode but nothing happens

Comment: not sure if my syntax is even right for store data. I was assuming i am able to store that texts my tweets that i get from my print in here.

Comment: But where is the code where you call that function? What are you passing to it?

Comment: here it is store_data(created_at, text, screen_name, tweet_id)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Those are completely different parameters to what you have shown here. But more importantly **where is that code**? Please show the whole thing in context, just posting snippets is making it impossible to work out what is going on.

Comment: I have posted whole code above, thanks very much.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you also please post the output you see in your console when you run this?

Comment: currently i run into 420 error because of wait rate limit even thought i defined listener = StreamListener(api=tweepy.API(wait_on_rate_limit=True))

Comment: but when it runs i see message "Tweet collected at " repated many times but i dont see any data in table. I have only 10 tweets in my twitter handle